# Getting the MySQLi error in class extension

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got a custom database class which extends the MySQLi class.

It connects to the database using `parent` in the `__construct` method.

Below is the portion of the query if the query is not successful, how do I return the error from the server?

```
$query =  parent::query($querystr, $resultmode);
    if (!$query) {
        $error = str_replace(
            'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use',
            'Syntax Error',
            mysqli_error(self::getInstance()));
        \core\debug::sqlerrorlog($error);
    } else {
        \core\debug::sqlSuccess();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), you just need to do `$this->error`.

As I understand, your problem now is that you don't pass a correct intsance of mysqli to `mysql_error` - maybe `self::getInstance()` is not doing what it supposed to, but I can't tell from what I see.